# Geometry Nodes - Generating geometry per instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I understand, with Geometry Nodes, that I can generate something procedurally, e.g., a tree.

I also know that, with "Distribute Points on Face," I can generate a forest from, say, a collection of tree models.

But, how would I generate a forest where each tree is individually procedurally generated? I know 'fields' represent values that are recomputed per instance. Is there, perhaps, one with a value of 'instance'? Or is this not possible yet?

I'm using Blender 3.0.

TIA

Comment: Hi, geometry node is quite a new feature (thus, less people can answer).  Attaching some diagram of what you think / screenshot of your node may help.

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible yet. But it hopefully is possible if the implement a loop or something like that

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in blender 3.1. For example i can generate 25 unique procedural trees on grid. All trunks and branches have random shape. All branches have random rotation. And it is possible to add a lot of other random details to this trees, making them much more different from each other.

[image]
[image]

Also it should be possible even in blender 3.0. But in blender 3.0 I face strange bug with capture attrubut for curve parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but your graph is impossible to make sense of. Doesn't matter anyway, though, as the *newer* question has kicked mine out as a dupe. :-P

Comment: That graph is visually cool to look at, but a nightmare to follow. This answer would be a lot more useful if you didn't lay out your nodes like a maze. In fact I've seen a few of your answers and most are very difficult to follow.