# Why won't Curve Parameter scale my instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I am trying to make (simplified example) the following:

- A curve
- with icospheres along its length
- where the radius and distance between icospheres is proportional to the distance from the start-point of the curve

What I'd like:

[image: target goal]

I understand that the `Curve Parameter` node is responsible for telling me how far along a curve I am, on the interval [0-1]. So my intuition is to pipe the curve param into both the scale of the instances, as well as the length offset of the `Resample Curve` node:

[image]

> **!IMPORTANT!** If you emulate my tree, make sure you have an `Add` node between `Curve Parameter` and `Resample`, or you'll get a huge number of icospheres and things will get slow :)

But this does not appear to work: Not only is the distance offset between spheres the same; they also are not scaled at all! (I've already confirmed that this is not due to imperceptibly small differences in scale)

Am I misunderstanding the Curve Parameter node? Is there another way I could better accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I've modified your scale so that the change in scale can be seen, and if I leave out the input to the resample length, I get  scaled icospheres, but they remain evenly spaced.  I don't think it's the Curve parameter that's giving you a problem but the way you're trying to use it to get unequal spacing in the resample.

Comment: Ah, indeed you're right; when I plug scale into `Instances` instead of the `Scale` node, things seem to work better, like you say: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfuMG.png. I wonder if that's what "Realized data" means in the info header, "Realized data in input geometry is ignored"

Comment: does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/250612/42221) help at all?  It's not the answer because it's about curves as instances, but maybe the resample discussion is useful

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't look like the solution there is working for me, but this gives me something to chew on! Thank you!

Comment: @j6m8 it says that data is ignored because it is not instances. You need to scale instances *after* they are created in Instance on points.

Comment: @Crantisz If you scale using a field, you can scale in the Instances on Points node.

Comment: @MartyFouts the question was "Why won't Curve Parameter scale my instances?"

Comment: @Crantisz "you can scale in the Instances on Points node" _using the Curve Parameter_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**This solution is 100% accurate only for a straight line.** Dealing with bezier lengths is very tricky and requires recursion, so really for a 100% accurate result on a curve I would expect only a Python solution to work...

Let's say each next icosphere is twice bigger. Let's manually calculate icos. positions.

If you have a single icosphere, you want to position it in the middle of the curve, 50% of it's length, or 1/2.

If you have two icos., you want the first to take 1/3, and the other to take 2/3 of the curve. So you want to position them at ${1\over3} \times {1\over2} = {1\over6}$ and ${1\over3} + {2\over3} \times {1\over2} = {2\over3}$. Multiplying by half, because the center is in half of the taken space.

3 icospheres positions:

- ${1\over7} \times {1\over2} = {1\over14}$
- ${1\over7} + {2\over7} \times {1\over2} = {2\over7}$
- ${1\over7} + {2\over7} + {4\over7} \times {1\over2} = {3\over7} + {2\over7} = {5\over7}$

4 icospheres positions:

- ${1\over15} \times {1\over2} = {1\over30}$
- ${1\over15} + {2\over15} \times {1\over2} = {2\over15}$
- ${1\over15} + {2\over15} + {4\over15} \times {1\over2} = {3\over15} + {2\over15} = {5\over15}$
- ${1\over15} + {2\over15} + {4\over15} + {8\over15} \times {1\over2} = {7\over15} + {4\over15} = {11\over15}$

You probably see a pattern by now:

- Space taken by each instance is a fraction with the numerator being the index raised to the power of 2...

0. $0^2 = 1$
1. $1^2 = 2$
2. $2^2 = 4$
3. $3^2 = 8$

- ...And the denominator being the total number of icos. raised to the power of 2, minus 1.

1. Icos.: $1/1$
2. Icos.: $1/3$, $2/3$
3. Icos.: $1/7$, $2/7$, $4/7$
4. Icos.: $1/15$, $2/15$, $4/15$, $8/15$

- Finally, the offset caused by previous instances follows the same pattern: 0, 1, 3, 7...

All those things can be calculated for each instance independently, without some iteration or recursion that geometry nodes don't yet support. The formula becomes:

$f = {2^{i-1}\over d} + {{2^i\over2}\over d} = {2^{i-1} + {2^i\div2}\over d}$

$d = 2^n -1$

where $f$ is a factor (% of the curve to sample a position at), $n$ is the number of icospheres and $i$ is the index of the icosphere.

[image]

Comment: While the geonode modifier has *Base* as one of the inputs, the node setup isn't quite ready to deal with changed base...

Comment: Wow, this is some really clever work!! It looks to me like it closely matches a non-straight bezier closely enough for my purposes; thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

The *Scale Instances* node operates on instances, not geometry, so it cannot be used before the *Instance on Points* node. There are two ways to scale instances:

**Scaling with the Instance on Points node:**

This is the simplest way to scale instances. Just plug the scale directly into the *Instance on Points* node, as shown in this image.
[image]
Note that the *Combine XYZ* node is unnecessary, since this is how Blender converts floats to vectors anyway.

**Scaling with the Scale Instances node:**

Using the *Scale Instances* node with the curve factor is slightly more difficult. Since the *Instance on Points* node does not transfer this data to instances, you need to use a *Capture Attribute* node before the *Instance on Points* node. Then you can place a *Scale Instances* node after the *Instance on Points* node, and use the captured attribute.
[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! It looks like the icospheres are still uniformly distributed along the curve; does that follow a similar solution on the Resample Curve node?

Answer (score 2):

You can scale after *Instances on Points* but if you use a field for the Scale input, you can also scale in *Instances on Points*.  This tree:

[image: node tree to scale instances on points]

produces this output:

[image: scaled instances]

if the original curve is an unmodified Bezier circle.

The remaining problem, and it has me stumped, is to scale the distance between the instances.  This tree

[image: tree that almost works]

does scale the length, as you can see by changing the constant in the *Multiply* node; but it scales the lengths evenly and it should scale by distance of the control point along the original curve.

Comment: Nice! I adapted your tree to get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bw9e.png I'm cheating by instancing a TON of spheres, and then choosing them using a scaled cyclical function (here, a Sine wave scaled by a log). It's still very clunky, because I get multiple spheres within a very tight distance of each other, but they at least overlap almost perfectly...

Comment: Here's the output of the tree I posted. Very brittle, and has a lot of overlapping geometry... https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV6Fi.png

Comment: You might want to try the [delete geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/delete_geometry.html) node to get rid of the overlaps?

Comment: Aha! I don't have an implementation yet, although [this](https://tomentos.com/blender/spiral/) is a good start, but the map range/multiply that drive the length have to be replaced by a Fibonacci sequence generator