# Geometry nodes. How to connect points with certain pattern?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Could you please help me to understand on how could I possibly connect the points with each other based on the following pattern: each red icosphere should be connected via thin line (low diameter cylinder) to 4 nearby yellow icospheres? At the same time each yellow icosphere should be connected to 2 nearby red icospheres.

[image: overall look of the scene]

Here is the simple geometry nodes setup that I currently have:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: i think that's the time for shifting to sverchok or animation nodes. I am pretty sure that GN cannot do this. But maybe Robin has another genius idea... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is too complex. That is why I will feel wrong if I will give you full answer. Because i do not want to do your jobe instead of you.

But i dislike that many people underestimate geonodes, even now when geonodes are very close to become more powerfull then old blender addons like sverchock or sorcar. In fact, geonodes have already surpassed sverchok and sorcar in several tasks. And they will become even more powerfull soon, because they have better blender integration and better support.

That's why i want to show that it is absolutely possible to do something like that in geonodes.

Here is solution for connecting 1 yellow ball to 1 closest red ball. And to connectig 1 red ball to 1 closest yellow ball. Also my node setup avoid situations when red line and yellow line have identical position and shape. In this case my node setup add a bend to booth lines, and create some kind of double bonds, like in molecule ball and stick models.

The key for this solution is comparing of positions of points between two point clouds. For this I use transfer atribute for target point cloud, and capture atribute for acting point cloud.

All setup:

[image]

Inside Ball_Gen group:

[image]

Inside Line_Gen group:

[image]

Inside Line_Cleanup group:

[image]

Larger result view:

[image]

Comment: i think you mean me with your "underestimate geonodes" comment - and shame on me, you are right - although i didn't give up my hope (that's why i commented this about Robin) and you just did it.  I can only bow to you and just admire your knowledge here. That's simply amazing. But maybe you saw some other comments of me about geonodes and hopefully you could see there, that i am a big fan of GN. And i can totally understand your "starter comment".

Comment: @Chris I mean a lot of people, not personaly you. For example, please, look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7Wbl8xp_w0 He got 630 likes under his video.

Comment: yes...but honestly...what are 630 likes? look at Blender guru's likes... ;) There will always be people who dislike the greatest things. And maybe he is a sverchok developer ;) and maybe you are a geometry nodes developer!? ;)

Comment: @Chris oh no no no. i am not blender developer :) i am just an ordinary blender user. I play with geonodes only for a three weeks. And if we talk about your "positive" comments, here is one more: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247566/geometry-nodes-generating-geometry-per-instance/250452#250452 ;) Please stop telling people that things are impossible.

Comment: well...at least if wrote "AFAIK" ...and until now i didn't know better. But no, i have to disagree - you are NOT an ordinary user but a damn intelligent and smart one. Which is...äh....rare. ;) may i ask what background you have...? studied math? professor in vector graph? ;)

Comment: @Chris i think that we already at the edge of offtopic. And we should stop now. My background is philosophy studies in some very so so university. I learned a lot about Aristotle, Immanuel Kant, Martin Heidegger and other smartest and coolest nerd guys of all times. I am grateful for my education as it made me a better man. But it don't help me with blender at all. Math is my weak point. For example I face a luck of my math knowledge every time when I try to do python scripting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is simply awesome what you have provided in this answer. It will help me a lot and let me learn a lot too.